# Kill Excel after user close Userform

Tags: vba, excel, kill-process

We have tried to fix these problem for a couple of days and we posted on another forums but still no answer, may be you guys can help us here.

I am having a problem with excel running after the Userform is closed, I think what I have supposed to end the application but it doesn't, it keeps excel running in the background and I have to end the process with task manager.
I created a vba file to copy a file to the temp folder and run a macro which opens excel and the userform.
Any help is appreciate it.

This is the vba script that copy and opens the macro:

```
    Dim FSO 
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    FSO.CopyFile "C:\pdfv6.xlsm", "C:\Windows\Temp\" 
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Windows\Temp\pdfv6.xlsm'!module1.macro1" 
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    objExcel.Application.Quit
```

And this is part of the vba module:

```
    Sub Macro1() 
    Application.Visible = False 
    UserForm1.Show 
    End Sub
    Set objExcel = Nothing
```

And this is the Sub that deals with closing the Userform and the application.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer) 
If CloseMode = 0 Then 
    Unload Me
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges = False 
    Application.Quit 
    End 
  End If 
  End Sub
```

Comment: You are having Excel create a new instance of itself? Why are you doing that?

Comment: Have you ever tried out an Add-On? (XLAM file) It seems like that would be a more logical approach.

Comment: @brax This excel macro will be use by several people in a network enviroment and we were having issues with read only documents etc. We don't want to use an addon, we want to use a shortcut on everybody's computers.

Comment: Why is the Set objExcel = Nothing after your End Sub?  Might want to try GetObject instead of CreateObject.

Comment: What method are you using to close everything ? Is it from the UserForm ? If so, then it will never work right. Where is the macro started from initially ? To me, it looks like you are trying to close excel on itself from a script which has to end before closing, which I'm not sure you can do. Closing from another workbook is simple.

Comment: What @Mitch said. The problem stems from implementing application logic in a form's code-behind, as I explain in the blog post linked above. The form has no business calling `Application.Quit`, `ThisWorkbook.Close`, or `End`ing execution, and `Unload Me` is bug-prone at best.

Comment: A network environment is the ideal use of an Addon. You have a read-only copy of the XLAM file on the network that everyone uses, and a full version for the developer to update and copy over the read-only file when there are changes, and everyone is then updated. You are going to have lots of problems doing it the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.
I was using Application.Quit twice
Once in the vbs script and then when I was closing the form.
I got rid of the one in the vbs script and everything is fine now.
thank you for your help.

Comment: Also you can't Set objExcel = Nothing before objExcel.Application.Quit... you'll get an error...

Comment: Stubbornly holding on to a flawed architecture is going to crumble, one day or another. Take the time to heed the advice you were given, and do things *right*. Code that "works" isn't necessarily *good code*.